# Status 401 on final payment completion issue

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am getting an error on the final stage of a Paypal payment, when I execute the it.  As far as I can see, its correct, I have no errors, but this is what it returns:

```
{"body":"","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Date":"Mon, 30 Jun 2014 18:10:56 GMT","Content-Length":"0","PROXY_SERVER_INFO":"host=slcsbjava1.slc.paypal.com;threadId=911","Paypal-Debug-Id":"b190b1adb3748","Server":"Apache-Coyote/1.1"},"status":401}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
execute = XHR.send('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/' + ppid[0].paymentid + '/execute', {

"header": {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + auth,
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
},

"parameters": {
  "payer_id": pid
}

});

console.log(execute);
```

I cannot see what the Paypal debug means, and I have looked it up, but mostly I see PHP issues rather than JS and cURL.

I saw on a post confusing REST API with Classic, but I have taken the instructions from the interactive guide by Paypal:  https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

Can anyone help me with this ?

**UPDATE**

Found out with debugging

```
auth
```

was empty, so I fixed it, and now getting a new error which is this:

```
 Error: {"message":"com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to java.util.Map","code":"0"} ( @ 8 : 45 ) -> var innerResult = GlobalXHRInner.send(method, url, GlobalJSON.stri
```

This error changes depending on how I send the final headers and parameters:

```
var newauth = "Bearer " + ppid[0].auth;

var info = {"headers": [{"Authorization": "'+newauth+'", "Content-Type" : "application/json"}], "parameters": [{"payer_id": "'+pid+'"}]};

console.log(info);

execute = XHR.send('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/' + ppid[0].paymentid + '/execute', info );

console.log(execute);

response.success(execute);
```

If I change :

```
var info = {"headers": [{"Authorization": "'+newauth+'", "Content-Type" : "application/json"}], "parameters": [{"payer_id": "'+pid+'"}]};
```

to this:

```
var info = '{"headers": [{"Authorization": "'+newauth+'", "Content-Type" : "application/json"}], "parameters": [{"payer_id": "'+pid+'"}]}';
```

By adding the quote, I get a invalid object error, which I have checked with a json validator and passed.  Really confused by these errors as I followed the guide :(

Answer (score 0):

This error message according to the PayPal documentation means this:

Authentication Errors
HTTP Status Code: 401

**Authentication errors** are often caused by issues related to access tokens:

Ensure the access token is included and correct.
 
Ensure the access token hasn’t expired. 
[PayPal Developer API Call Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)

Here is additional information on Access tokens from [PayPal Developer Access Token](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/):

When you make the API calls, make request by adding the access token in the ‘Authorization’ header using the following syntax (as defined in the OAuth 2.0 protocol):

```
Authorization: {tokenType} {accessToken}
```

Example: `Authorization: Bearer EEwJ6tF9x5...4599F`
Access token validity and expiration

PayPal-issued access tokens can be used to access all the REST API endpoints. These tokens have a finite lifetime and you must write code to detect when an access token expires. You can do this either by keeping track of the ‘expires_in’ value returned in the response from the token request (the value is expressed in seconds), or handle the error response **(401 Unauthorized)** from the API endpoint when an expired token is detected.

Comment: thank you, I found after debugging it was the auth variable that was empty, for it only to give me a new error which I updated, as i'm not sure if its part of the problem as I get a different error if i change one thing, which is still apparently valid ?